# Disable multiline selection by mouse drag

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouse, selection

When I reach the top bor bottom bound of my JTable the JTable enable the multiselection with mouse "dragged". So in the middle of my table I can scroll with dragging the mouse, but at top or bottom the table selects multiple rows when dragging the mouse. It's behaves like pressing CTRL and the drag the mouse. But i don't want this feature, so how can i disable this function?

Comment: `table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION)`

Answer (score 0):

Set the selection mode of your tables selection model to SINGLE_SELECTION.